# Run task before repositories are added and dependencies are resolved

Tags: gradle

I'm working on compiling python bindings using gradle.
There is a [plugin by linkedin](https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle) that facilitates that.

They also include a project called the pivy-importer that converts python dependencies into an ivy repository.

I've created a gradle plugin that wraps the pivy-importer so that it can run as a python task.

My repositories are declared like this:

```
repositories {
    pyGradlePyPi()
    ivy {
        name 'pypi-local'   //optional, but nice
        url "${project.buildDir.path}/pythonIvy"
        layout "pattern", {
            ivy "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision].ivy"
            artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
            m2compatible = true
        }
    }
}
```

The problem, however, is that the repositories are being loaded before the plugin executes.

The first task that the python task runs is `pinRequirements` so I was adding my cusom `pythonImporter` task before that like this:

```
pinRequirements.dependsOn pythonImporter
```

However, even when I do that, the console shows that the `pythonImporter` task is running before but as soon as it tries to assemble the dependencies, it can't find them even though they do exist in the file system.

If you rerun the task again, however, it passes because the first run added the repository to the file system.

**TL;DR**

I need a way to run a task before dependencies are looked up under using a project's configured `repositories` are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the tasks execution to my `buildSrc` subproject and made the `build` task depend upon its execution.
This works because the `buildSrc` project is always evaluated before the rest of the projects so you can do "before build" logic there.